# Solving a pursuit-evasion game

Tags: algorithm, graph

Let's say we have a simple connected and undirected graph G(V,E). The game is played with two players. For each game, player A starts at a node t, and player B at a node v. There is also a node d which is the same for every game.

In the game, player A always plays first. His goal is to reach node d before player B reaches him (player B can't go to node d). Player B's goal, on the other hand, is to reach the node where A is. If players A,B have been in nodes x,y, respectively, in a previous round, and these positions are repeated again, the match ends in a tie. In every round the player which has priority must move to a neighboring node.

What I need is to make an algorithm that gives as output the result of this game for every possible starting combination t,v∈V (where t≠v).

What I've done so far is a dynamic programming O(|V|3) solution. We can record all possible states of this game as (position of player A, position of player B, next player to move), and find all the possible resulting states for every state.

Could this be done any better?

Comment: The size of the output is about V^2, the same as the number of states you need to enumerate in your DP algorithm. So it doesn't look like there's much room for improvement.

Comment: @n.m. Isn't the output O(1) size?It just determines who won or if it ended as a tie.I hoped that maybe we didn't have to check all states but  possibly find a greedy criterion for each player's next move.

Comment: You said you need to print who wins for every (v, t) pair.

Comment: It's quick to check if Player A can make it to `d` before Player B can make it to any of the nodes on Player A's shortest path.

Comment: @Richard it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @n.m.  An other solution i thought was:Let's say player A is in a u node.From the neighboring nodes he will choose the one belonging in the sortest path between u,d as long as it is further than 1 from player B(otherwise in the next turn player B will catch him).If this node is not further than 1 he will find a new shortest path which does not contain this node.If there is no such path(which means he has to visit a previsited node)he can not win so he tries to end the game as draw.

Comment: Concerning player B if he can't reach player A as @richard sayng he can't win.Otherwise he will try to block player's A path(coming as close as 1) to it as soon as possible.What i mean is if u,d is the shortest path player A is following he will try to block it in a node as close as possible to u.To find this node we can probably use bfs knowing how much time it will take A to get there.

Comment: It is meaningless to calculate the shortest path, or the shortest path that doesn't contain the node B is currently in, because B moves.

Comment: @n.m. I didn't mean it to solve the problem. It's a _O(N)_ filter that potentially solves a broad class of instances. Calculating shortest paths gives you a lot of traction here even if they're not a general solution.